# Как воспроизвести звук вместе с текстом в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, разработка-игр

Помогите пожалуйста. Делаю игру крестики нолики, хотел добавить победный звук,который воспроизводится тогда, когда  по окончанию игры, выводится текст в котором указывается победитель (X или О)

Comment: Есть компонент AudioSource (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html), вещай его на GameObject и через него играй клип.